# Subscribe to change to template html inside "with"

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a bootstrap modal with

```
data-bind="showModal:selectedItem, with: selectedItem"
```

making in visible only when *selectedItem* is selected and it all works well.
For modal body I have the following code, and it chooses for different templates loaded in the page based on a computed value of *templateToUse* that checks *selectedItem* for a specific property, and also this works well.

```
<div class="col-xs-12" data-bind="template: { name: $root.templateToUse }"></div>
```

The problem comes when i try to run some jquery DOM manipulation on my templates, since they are accualy not "html" until they are loaded, based on the above code I figured I could subscribe to *selectedItem* and do the manipulation after load, but

```
self.selectedItem.subscribe(function (newitem) {
    alert($(".modal").html());
});
```

alerts an empty string, meaning the template is not yet loaded, and I cannot make any manupilation yet. Is there any way i can subscribe to the data binding of the template instead, that fires when the template is changed?

Comment: DOM manipulations should be avoided when using knockout. Isn't there a way to use some binding in place of these manipulations? (like with the `if` binding, `visible` binding, `css` binding, etc.)

Comment: I have to run to following code
function checkCustomInputType(element, type) {
    $(element).attr("type", type);
    var invalidValue = '';
    if (type == 'date') {
        invalidValue = 'invalid-date-value';
    }
    $(element).val(invalidValue);

    return !(input.value === invalidValue);
} each time a new template is lodaded, to see if the browser supports the date-type on an input, otherwise add a different class to show a javascript date picker.

Comment: Then I guess you can use a [`css` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)

Comment: Of course! Well thank you for putting me on the correct path.